# Dovecot: How can I prevent sieve filter from being applied to some mail users?

Tags: dovecot, sieve

We have an emarket@example.com mailbox that receives orders from customers. Postfix redirects such emails to the email addresses of our sales managers, as well as to the special address parser@example.com, which is used by some analytical software. For this, a file named "Virtual" has been created in the Postfix folder with the following contents:

```
emarket@example.com   manager1@example.com,manager2@example.com,manager3@example.com,parser@example.com
```

In addition, Dovecot places all such emails in the Orders folder of each sales manager. For this, a Sieve filter rule has been created:

```
require ["fileinto", "envelope"];
if envelope: is "to" "emarket@example.com" {
  fileinto "Orders";
  stop;
}
```

But the problem is that the analytics software that uses the parser@example.com mailbox is subscribed only to the default Inbox folder. And it doesn't know how to work with the Orders folder. So I need to somehow prevent the filter from being applied to the parser@example.com mailbox. How can I do this using Dovecot or Sieve?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the problem was solved using the "Delivered-To" header:

```
require ["fileinto", "envelope"];

if allof (envelope :is "to" "emarket@example.com",
        not header :is "Delivered-To" "parser@example.com")
{
  fileinto "Orders";
  stop;
}
```